# Is there a sane default for std::tr1::function?

Tags: c++, tr1

I spent some time googling but didn't really find anything.  I want to be able to do this:

```
std::tr1::function<void()> foo(SOME_DEFAULT_FUNCTION_THAT_DOES_NOTHING);
//
//Some code that could possibly assign foo
//
foo();
```

Otherwise I have to do this:

```
std::tr1::function<void()> foo;
//
//Some code that could possibly assign foo
//
if(foo)
{
    foo();
}
```

I realize I could just make a function that does nothing, but I am looking for some standard way of not having to deal with checking to see if the function was given a value ala the null object pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void noop() { }`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a `boost::optional<std::tr1::function<void()> >`? That way it allows it to be set or not, and you can use an if check to see if the function has been set.

Comment: I can already do an if check.  I wanted to avoid the if check and be able to execute the function in either case.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use

```
void noop(...) {}
```